# Append Filename to RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a folder containing my data files. Each file has a size of about 1 GB.

What I need is the filename inside the RDD.

Following does not work as expected:

```
import glob
rdds = []
for filename in glob.iglob('/data/*'):
    rdd = sc.textFile(filename).map(lambda row: (filename, row))
    rdds.append(rdd)

allData = sc.union(rdds)
```

using this, `filename` is always the filename of the last read file

What I also tried:

```
import glob
rdds = []
for filename in glob.iglob('/data/*'):
    def f(name=filename):
        return name
    rdd = sc.textFile(filename).map(lambda row: (f(), row))
    rdds.append(rdd)

allData = sc.union(rdds)
```

But that produces the error: `Broadcast can only be serialized in driver`

`sc.wholeTextFile()` is not an option because the single files are to big.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
import functools

def proc(f):
    return sc.textFile(f).map(lambda x: (f, x))

rdd = functools.reduce(
    lambda rdd1, rdd2: rdd1.union(rdd2),
    (proc(f) for f in glob.glob("/data/*")))
```

or with `sc.union`:

```
sc.union([proc(f) for f in glob.glob("/data/*")])
```