# add filename to RDD rows on wholeTextFiles

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I've been googling and trying this for a couple of hours with no luck, hope any of you can provide advice.

I'm reading a large number of files into a Spark RDD, and I want to append the filename, which contains a timestamp, into each of the rows of the RDD. So far this is what I got.

```
def append_name(x):
    filename = x[0].split('\n') #take the filename
    content = x[1].split('\n') #take the content
    output = [(row.split(','), filename) for row in content]
    flattened = [item for sublist in output for item in sublist]
    return flattened

data_file = sc.wholeTextFiles("data/").flatMap(lambda l: append_name(l))

data_file.take(1)
```

My output looks like this:

```
[[u'25689119206459',
  u'True',
  u'3',
  u'main',
  u'used_car',
  u'Huzhou',
  u'False',
  u'False',
  u'21824706815494',
  u'0',
  u'http://jump.zhineng.58.com/clk?target=mv7V0A-b5HTh',
  u'0\r'],
 [u'file:/home/user/data/light_2016-06-01T04-02-27_node1.csv']]
```

Which is still a list of lists... even when I have flattened it. Any ideas of what I'm missing? I also tried using the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734760/append-filename-to-rdd) and got the same results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> def flatten(pair):
...     f, text = pair
...     return [line.split(",") + [f] for line in text.splitlines()]
... 
>>> rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("README.md").flatMap(flatten)
>>> for x in rdd.take(3):
...     print(x)
...     
['# Apache Spark', 'file:/some-path/README.md']
['', 'file:/some-path/README.md']
['Spark is a fast and general cluster computing system for Big Data. It provides', 'file:/some-path/README.md']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simpler version:

```
allInOneRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("data/").flatMap(lambda l:[line+","+f for line in c.splitlines()])
```